# Which is the preferred circuit layout? Horizontal vs. Vertical (Combinational logic)

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have 2 equivalent circuits

Picture 1 (Compact, a bit messier)

[image]

Picture 2 (Easier to read, less compact)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A is preferred, all things being equal, BUT all things are not equal.

B contains useful information that is missing from A and more clearly shows what you are seeking to achieve. This is trivial in many cases, but if it is for teaching purposes, A could be drawn to be equally clear.

I suggest that you try redrawing A to match the above (and B to remove the clarity) and see what you get.

A seems to be purposefully messy :-) :-( .

---

Turning a few labels around and changing inputs to left side would make something like this equally clear.

[image]